# Malloc involving structures

Tags: c

Fine, let me wipe this question and try again:

I have two structures defined as follows:

## LangData

```
typedef struct
{
    char languageName[60];
    char stopwords[2000][60];
    int wordcount;
} LangData;
```

The first structure contains the name of a language, a list of words corresponding to that language, and a counter to track the number of words.

## AllData

```
typedef struct
{
    int languageCount;
    LangData languages[];
} AllData;
```

The second structure contains primarily an array of the first structure, and a counter to keep track of the number of languages I am working with.

I need to dynamically allocate space for languages[] because there is not a specific number of languages I am dealing with.

This is what I have done to try and solve the issue, but I am unsure if it is correct. It is one of many areas within my code that could be causing issues and I am trying to pinpoint the problem

```
int langCount = 0;

while(readdir(d)) //d is a directory containing language files.
  langCount++;

AllData *data = malloc(offsetof(AllData, languages) +
        sizeof(LangData)*langCount);
data->languageCount = langCount;
```

Comment: No need to be an expert. Just use a debugger.

Comment: "I don't know where my problem lies" and "I apologize again for the mountain of code" means you're not quite ready to bring the problem to us. Narrow it down; write a smaller program that reproduces your issue, and figure out where the issue lies, and then come back to us.

Comment: Or ask a more specific question. For example, take the code out, describe the problem, your platform, and your preferred method of debugging, and ask for help applying that method.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I have altered my question.

Comment: The malloc is correct if you change the `offsetof` expression to `sizeof(AllData)` or `sizeof *data`

Comment: To help find where the problem is in a larger codebase, make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

The nested structure is not a pointer, so there is no need to allocate it. For the `AllData` struct use:

```
AllData *all = malloc ( sizeof(*all));
```

Edit:

Just seen that you are using the nested one as array. Just allocate the nested structure in the same way as the other one after you allocated AllData:

```
all->langdata = malloc ( sizeof(*all->langdata) * n);
```

Where n is the number of elements...
I would also change the definition from LangData lang[] to LangData *data